# Remove leading slash from <link href> and other references using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a dev server where I've uploaded a copy of a clients old site to:

```
/dev/name/old/
```

Within the old site, there are a lot of references to

```
/
```

Example:

```
/css/stylesheet.css
/js/script.js
/images/img.jpg
```

Desired structure:

```
/dev/name/old/css/stylesheet.css
/dev/name/old/js/script.js
/dev/name/old/images/img.jpg
```

Is there a way or redirecting all references with a leading slash to the sub directory, with a htaccess file that is in the sub directory?

Apologies for repeat question, I've tried a number of solutions but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the header of all of your client's old site:

```
<base href="/dev/name/old/">
```

Otherwise, there's no way to differentiate a link from the old site to a link from the current site.

Comment: would this not end up with /dev/name/old//css because the links have leading slashes already?

Comment: @Tisch It will have 2 slashes between `old` and `css` but that shouldn't matter. Or you could remove the slash after `old`.